# How to allow connection between ec2 instances in different regions?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, security-groups

I have 10 instances with a security group in Oregon and another 10 in Virginia.
How to add edit security group(rules) to allow traffic between them??

Comment: What have you tried? You can set up a VPN, or whitelist their public IP addresses.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/aws-multiple-region-multi-vpc-connectivity/

Answer (score 1):

If your EC2 instances in both regions are located in public subnets with public IP addresses, then you can add each server's IP address to your security groups. There is a limit of 50 inbound or outbound rules per security group, so you won't be able to open more than 4 or 5 ports per IP address per security group. This can be raised to 100 rules by contacting AWS support but the number of security groups per network interface drops to 2.

[Security Groups Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Appendix_Limits.html#vpc-limits-security-groups)

If your EC2 instances are located in private subnets or without public IP addresses, then you will need to setup VPC networking. The link that @Tim provided is a good start. Double check first that your VPCs do not have overlapping address space (CIDRs). If the CIDR blocks overlap, you will have to fix that first by creating a new VPC in one of the regions that uses a different CIDR block and move the EC2 instances into the new VPC (by creating AMIs and then relaunching the instances).

[Multiple Region Multi-VPC Connectivity](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/aws-multiple-region-multi-vpc-connectivity/)

I use Openswan to connect two VPCs in different regions together. Here is a good article by [medium.com](https://medium.com/) that shows how to setup everything up. Pretty simple if you understand VPNs.

[AWS Region to Region VPC Connectivity with OpenSwan and VPC VPN](https://medium.com/connecting-the-clouds/aws-region-to-region-vpc-connectivity-with-openswan-and-vpc-vpn-c22610bdc3ad)